# Ionic + iOS keyboard: display the button to lower/hide the keyboard

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, keyboard

In my Ionic (1) app, I have a search field (where you can see "kelly" in the screen capture below) which filters the list below.

However, the iOS keyboard doesn't offer the option to "lower" or "hide" the keyboard to be able to watch the list comfortably once filtered.

As you can see on the screenshot, there's only a "return" button on the keyboard, but it does nothing!

Any idea how to display the button to lower the iOS keyboard?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think if you leave the `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false)` with false
It can has the hide button in the keyboard.